# Is `DispatchQueue.main.async` block in viewWillAppear always called after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear, dispatch-queue

I wanted to change the collection view's contentOffset.x right after pushing VC.
So I called `collectionView.setContentOffset(~)` in viewWillAppear.
But It didn't work because of auto layout cycle.

However, if I call `collectionView.setContentOffset` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` block, IT WORKS!

The code is below:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        collectionView.setContentOffset(
            CGPoint(x: currentFolderIndex * collectionView.bounds.width), y: 0), 
            animated: false
        )
    }
}
```

I figured out why it had worked when I printed the order of layout methods.

[image]

`DispatchQueue.main.async` block is called after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Does it always work like this?
Why does it work like this?
I'm so curious!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async` basically says "do it when you have time". So it will be done at an indeterminate time in the future (generally not too long after), and probably after finishing what is currently being done. And the calling function does not wait for the code to be executed on the main queue before continuing.

So in your case, when calling `async`, the UI thread finishes what he is doing, calling `viewWillLayoutSubViews`, doing autolayout, etc,... and when he has finished and has time, he executes the `setContentOffset` asynchronously.

However, in theory it does not guarantees it will always be the same order : UI thread could find time before, or could be overbooked and not have time before `viewDidAppear`... But in practical, I think you are safe assuming it will be the same order 99,99% of the time.

Note : In other situations, you could think of using `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, which would say "Do it ASAP and I'm waiting for you". However, this is probably is a terrible idea, especially if you are in the UI thread : you would be waiting in the UI thread for the UI thread to do something else, and you cannot get out of that - it is a deadlock. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258413/dispatchqueue-crashing-with-main-sync-in-swift).